# Fid on QGIS 3.12

Tags: qgis, numbering, virtual-field

I am using QGIS 3.12.
I created a new geopackage and in the fid field I want to see the feature number, according to the number of features I have created but it only say "autogenerate". What can I do?

Comment: Maybe use `row_number` in the Field Calculator.

Comment: I tried but if I delite one feature it keeps counting like it still excite

Comment: Please explain what is your aim. The primary key in GeoPackage must be "integer autoincrement" by the standard. It means that the value is increasing steadily and deleting features does not free the used PK values for reuse.

Comment: Ok. My geopackge as a layer of trees. I want each tree to have a number 1 2 3 etc. I want that this number will be input automaticly so when I create a new tree he will get a new number automaticly.But also if i have 5 trees and  than I delete one the next tree will be 5 not 6.

Comment: But if you have 5 trees (1, 2, 3, 4, 5), if you delete one (3) and the next tree is 5, it will be a duplicate ! If you just want a unique `fid` in the end, just update the field with `$id` in the field calculator at the end of digitizing.

Comment: You are absolutely right. Is there a way I can define this update as an "Action"  or I have to do it manually  in the field calculatet every time at the end of digitizing?